# Why does this hourly scheduled firebase cloud function using .schedule('0 * * * *') not run at 2am local time?

Tags: firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions

It runs for every hour except 2am Pacific/Auckland time.

There has not been any daylight savings changes.

I just deployed this yesterday so this issue has only occurred once.

Other functions with the same schedule have the same issue.

```
export const scheduledActivateAdvanceMemberships = functions
  .region('us-east1')
  .pubsub
  .schedule('0 * * * *')
  .timeZone('Pacific/Auckland')
  .onRun(myFunction)
```

[image: logs]

[image: gcp function]

**UPDATE (1 day later):**

It ran at 2am this time with no problems.
I will keep an eye on it and close this question if it does not occur again. Very strange.

**UPDATE (2 weeks later):**
No more issues. Not sure why it happened the first time.

Comment: Hi @MadMac , does this issue still occur on your scheduled function?

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB it has not occurred again after the first time. I have no idea why it happened though.